# Serializer in django doesn't have any data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-serializer

```
>>> user = User.objects.create_user(username = "testusername", password = "testpassword")
>>> user_serializer = UserSerializer(user)
>>> user_serializer
UserSerializer(<User: testusername>):
>>> user_serializer.is_valid()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/Virtual Environments/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 228, in is_valid
    'Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was '
AssertionError: Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.
>>> user_serializer.data
{}
```

The UserSerializer is:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Username: {self.data['username']}  Password: {self.data['password']}"

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

I don't understand what's going wrong. The user_serializer.data is empty.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You should inherit your serializer class from **`serializers.ModelSerializer`** instead of `serializers.Serializer`

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

Then serialize your data,

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username = "testusername", password = "testpassword")
user_serializer = UserSerializer(user)
print(user_serializer.data)
```

---

**Note:**
If you wish to use **`serializers.Serializer`** class, you should specify the fields explicitly as,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says itself:

> Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed
>   when instantiating the serializer instance.

There's no need to call `user_serializer.is_valid()` since you are passing a `User` object to the serializer. Try removing it.

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username = "testusername", password = "testpassword")
user_serializer = UserSerializer(user)
print(user_serializer.data)
```

Comment: the data is still empty